# Pull from one GitLab repository and push into another one

Tags: intellij-idea, gitlab, push, pull

So I have a public repository from my lecturer on GitLab, which I cloned into intellij via "import VCS" (https Link). Now I want to always push into my own repository in GitLab and not the public repository. How can i do this in intellij or where else can I set this up?

I already tried to copy the project into a new project and push seperately but this isnt a good solution because then i need to copy everything manually whenever new things are being added in the public repository and i cant just pull from the public repository.
The optimal solution would be, that i can pull from the public repository but push my commits into my own repository in GitLab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

clone the public repository using command

> git clone repo_path

> git add .

> git commit -m "comment"

> git push origin main

Answer (score 0):

You can clone your lecturer project.

Once it's done, go to `Git | Manage remotes` and add your private repostiory there.

Once it is added there, when you decide to Push -> go to `Git | Push` and then you can click on `origin` and choose desired remote. This way you can choose your target remote and update your local project from your teacher's repository.